# How to set column header in list box?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with displaying column headers in a ListBox in my userform. Everything is working fine but could not show the headers. The header start in Row B8 and I try changing the code around a bit but still doesn't work. Any help is Appreciated Thank you! :)) (Quick Note I'm running Excel 2016)

VBA Code:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim DB As Worksheet

LastRow = Sheets("DataBase Entry").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = Sheets("DataBase Entry").Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set DataRange = Sheets("DataBase Entry").Range("B9").Resize(LastRow, lastCol)

'populate the data array
dataArray = DataRange.Value

'populate the Listbox control
With Me.lbData 'With loop
  .Clear
  .ColumnCount = lastCol
  .ColumnHeads = True
  For j = 1 To lastCol
    .ColumnWidths = .ColumnWidths & ";100"
  Next j
  .List = dataArray
  Me.lbData.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Column headers will be displayed only if the data is set via `RowSource`. If you assign the data by assigning it to `.List` or use `AddItem`, no header is displayed. As workaround, either add the header as first row into the list (I know, this is not very nice), or put labels above the listbox.

Comment: @FunThomas Does that mean there is a possible workaround with taking `dataArray` and pasting it into a hidden worksheet, and using that as a `RowSource`?

Comment: No need for a hidden sheet when there's already a contiguous table of data on "DataBase Entry"...

Comment: @Toddleson: That should do, yes. However, Ted is right, in this specific case the `RowSource` could be set directly to  `DataRange`.